# Are bank accounts (same bank) accessible from outside of the U.S

Tags: united-states, banking, international, security

This is a bit of a subjective question, perhaps more of a safety concern.

I currently bank with Citibank (U.S), and since I know they have branches in other countries, could bankers in those other countries access accounts in the U.S? or only U.S branches can access your account?

Comment: Have you asked Citibank? You might even frame the question that you might be overseas for a time and wonder if you can access your US account from foreign branches.

Comment: What do you mean by access? Can they see your balances and transactions? or can you walk into the overseas branch and do transactions like deposits and withdrawals?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: That's a great idea, I'll do that.

Comment: @Dheer: I was thinking of balances and transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In today's computerized world, most of the operations run out of global centers. So all the back office operations would be running from places outside of US [like Singapore, India, London, Hong kong, Philippines etc ...] Citibank has a huge operations outside US [mostly in India, Singapore] and technically all the authorized staff can access accounts. The people [bankers] in the Citibank branches outside US however would not have access. The technology staff [quite a few outside US] would have limited access to the data.

Comment: Working in a Bank I can tell you it really is limited. Only people who really need have access [seniority does not play role]. Plus all access are periodically audited.